# How do you reliably find an iOS Calendar?

Tags: ios, eventkit

The `calendarIdentifier` property on `EKCalendar` says that a full sync will lose the identifier.  How are we supposed to track a calendar then?  It's not possible to just trust the name of the calendar because nothing prevents the user from changing the name.  Not only that, nothing prevents two calendars from having the same name.

What I'm basically dealing with is that my `Team` object has an associated subscribed calendar, and I need a way to link those two together.  The obvious solution is to store the `calendarIdentifier` in the `Team` object once it's created, but that won't work based on the documentation.

Comment: I think your analysis is correct, you can't with the current EventKit. It's pretty limited in a lot of ways. Presumably all you can do is stick to the `calendarIdentifier` and if that doesn't match up anymore, query the calendar name (and prompt the user in case of dupes). If you have a local cache you can also query the most likely peer by the contents of the calendar to help with the ().